# sharepoint proxy web part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, proxy

We have several asp.net web applications we've built and we also want to embed them into various sharepoint pages.  We need to have them look like standalone applications when viewed in their own pages, but also have them look like they fit within the sharepoint page when embedded.  We are doing this currently with IFrames and it works ok, but I'm wondering if there is some sort of proxy web part where we can configure the web part to point to an existing web app and it will proxy the contents through from the web app into the sharepoint page removing the need for an IFrame.  Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the "Page Viewer Web Part" that behaves just like an iFrame in a more user-friendly way.

Something more advanced existed in SharePoint 2003 with Office Web Components, but does not works on 2007 (if that is your version).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Jan Tielen's smart part on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/smartpart). It allows regular user controls to be embedded in SharePoint.